# Adding health back to the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a game where the player has 10 health. Each time he loses health his heart drops down by 0.5 . To give the player some hope I decided to add dropable hearts to enemies. These hearts can fill a value of 2 health.

The problem is that the health script I made is with the public Int health. This doesn't allow " <, >, +, - " And I have no clue how to adapt towards this.

My health script

```
    [Header ("Max/Starting Health")]
    public int maxHealth;
    [Header ("Current Health")]
    public int health;

    void Start () {
        health = maxHealth;
    }

    public bool TakeHeal (int amount) {
        if (dead || health == maxHealth)
            return false;

        health = Mathf.Min (maxHealth, health + amount);

        if (OnTakeHealEvent != null)
            OnTakeHealEvent.Invoke();


        return true;
    }
```

The HealthPickup Script

```
﻿using UnityEngine;

public class HealthBoost : MonoBehaviour
{
    Health health;

    public float healthBonus = 2;

    void Awake()
    {
      health = FindObjectOfType<Health>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
      if(health < health.maxHealth)
      {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        health = health + healthBonus;
      }
    }
}
```

I was thinking of adapting the healthpickup script more towards the takeheal. But I don't know how I can make this collidable with the gameObject

Comment: You are destroying the pickup gameobject before even adding the health. Just destroy it after.

Comment: @MateusFernandes FYI destruction of game objects doesn't happen immediately unless you're using `DestroyImmediate()`

Comment: @Iggy Thats true, but it is still better to add the health before marking the object to be destroyed since we have very little to no control of when the garbage collector will run.  It is also a good idea to note that functions will still finish out if we destroy the object in the script.

Comment: @Eddge sure, I prefer to put it at the end too. But keep in this is not to do with GC. [Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html): "Actual object destruction is always delayed until after the current Update loop, but will always be done before rendering."

Comment: @Iggy ahh, but trigger isn't in the update loop, it happens in the physics loop.  That happens before the update loop so that probably means it might be safe to do in reverse order but as you stated I like the other way and dont like to tempt fate =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to modify the health value that is inside the health object:

```
if(health.health < health.maxHealth) {
    health.health = health.health + healthBonus;
}
```

Comment: True, but the problem is still that the FLOAT cannot be converted to the INT value it says I could cast it? But I have no clue what that means.

Comment: `(int)myFloat` so in this case: `health.health = health.health + (int)healthBonus`

Comment: Altough it does trigger and the health does dissapear. It does not seem to increase the players health back ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I would remove the if statement and put a clamp at the end `if health > max; health = max`.

Comment: Maxhealth isn't the problem in this case since the health can never go over the maxhealth. The problem is that the user collides with the PickupHealth, thus destroying the gameobject. But the health gained is never registered within the player.